# PrimeFaces, how to avoid concatenation of p:column in p:selectOneMenu selected value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I would like to use p:selectOneMenu with custom contents with p:columns (as shown in http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf) and I would like to show the selected value in the drop-down field with less information than the ones shown in the drop-down list of possible values.

For example, the code below should show only *bnkCod* after selection (e.g. '1'). 

Instead it shows the concatenation of *bnkCod* and *bnkNam* (e.g. '1 Bank 1').

*bnkCod* and *bnkNam* are both String and the Converter works correctly.

Can anybody help me troubleshooting the problem ?

**JSF:**

```
 <p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.bank}" converter="bankCodeConverter" var="p">  
              <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
              <f:selectItems value="#{bean.banks}" 
                             var="bank" itemLabel="#{bank.bnkCod}" itemValue="#{bank}"/>                
              <p:column>  
                  #{p.bnkCod}
              </p:column>                
              <p:column>  
                  #{p.bnkNam}  
              </p:column>  
 </p:selectOneMenu>
```

**Bean:**

```
List<Bank> banks = new ArrayList<Bank>();
banks.add(new Bank("1","Bank 1"));
banks.add(new Bank("2","Bank 2"));
```

**Converter:**

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=Bank.class,value="bankCodeConverter")
public class MeansOfPaymentConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        //... retrieve bean
        return bean.getBanksMap().get(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if(value instanceof Bank) 
            return ((Bank) value).getBnkCod();
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.4 and the problem shows up in both Safari 6.0 and Firfefox 18.0.1

Comment: I don't understand your question: Why are you expecting it to show only ` #{p.bnkNam}` when you've clearly specified that both fields should show by adding `<p:column>  
                         #{p.bnkCod}
                       </p:column> ` along with the `bnkName`?

Comment: Hi @kolossus, let me rephrase my question then. A drop-down list displays the selected value in a field together with a list of possible values when it gets activated, right ? I'd like to have only   '#{p.bnkCod}' in the selected value, but both '#{p.bnkCod}' and '#{p.bnkNam}' inside the entries of possible values.

Comment: I installed the PrimeFaces Showcase (PrimeFaces-3.5-SNAPSHOT on Mojarra-2.1.10) on my local Tomcat 7.0.25 and I've noticed a different behavior between my local installation and the live ShowCase. In the 'content with filter' seletOneMenu in http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf, once I select the entry for messi I get 'Messi' in the selectOneMenu field value.
In my local installation when I do the same I get 'Messi - 10' in the field value.
So, my code is probably correct, but there's something, somewhere else, to be fixed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any solution to the problem.
I therefore decided to show both values 'p.bnkCod' and 'p.bnkNam', which was acceptable enough.

Answer (score 1):

The way I found to solve this was by overwriting selectOneMenu widget js code.

1) Open primefaces jar file and look for primefaces.js under META-INF/resources/primefaces
2) Copy code of PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneMenu into a new js file and call it from your main app page (probably a template)
3) Overwrite method setLabel with following code:

```
setLabel : function(a) {
  var theLabel = a;
  var labelArray = a.split('\n');
  for ( var idx = 0; idx < labelArray.length; idx++) {
    if (labelArray[idx] != '') {
      theLabel = labelArray[idx];
      break;
    }
  }
  if (this.cfg.editable) {
    this.label.val(theLabel);
  } else {
    if (theLabel == "") {
      this.label.html("&nbsp;");
    } else {
      this.label.text(theLabel);
    }
  }
}
```

When you use columns, label comes in the format \ncol1\ncol2\ncolN. So my workaround is to get the first non empty string after spliting the label for \n.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this with columns:

```
<p:column rendered="#{p.bnkCod == bean.bank.bnkCod}">
  #{p.bnkCod}
</p:column>
<p:column rendered="#{p.bnkCod == bean.bank.bnkCod}">
  #{p.bnkNam}
</p:column>
<p:column colspan="2" rendered="#{p.bnkCod != bean.bank.bnkCod}">
  #{p.bnkCod}
</p:column>
```

Also update yor list, by adding this inside `selectOneMenu`:

```
<p:ajax update="@this" process="@this"/>
```

Comment: Hi @partlov, thanks for your message. I tried the solution you proposed, but what I obtained is a drop-down list with three columns where the first two are correctly filled only for the selected entry (shown also in the drop-down value) and all the other entry only have the third column filled in with their bnkCod. 
I'd like to have only two columns in the drop-down list (showing bnkCod and bnkNam), and only the selected entry's bnkCod in the drop-down value.